# Bitrix : About install im.bitrix.info to own server

Tags: frameworks, installation, bots, skype, bitrix

I bought bitrix self host version then I installed it to my server.

But when checking I see all message interact with Bot Framwork all through to bitrix server: `im.bitrix.info`, can I setup a application as `im.bitrix.info` by my self at my own server for controlling.

I need it because many cases I can debug what problem with skype bot or bitrix problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

> Some organizations may restrict Internet access due to security reasons. In this case Firewall controls the incoming and outgoing network traffic based on predetermined security rules. In order to to be able to work with your Bitrix24 account, please make sure you have the following addresses allowed in your Firewall: `*.bitrix24.com`, `*.bitrix24.net` (Bitrix24.Network, authorization)
>
> International domains: 
>   `*.bitrix24.de` (Germany)
>   `*.bitrix24.es` (Spanish speaking countries)
>   `*.bitrix24.com.br` (Portuguese speaking countries)
>   `*.bitrix24.cn` (China)
>   `*.bitrix24.in` (India)
>   `*.bitrix24.eu` (Europe)
>   `*.bitrix24.fr` (France)
>
> For all of the above mentioned addresses we recommend to allow subnet mask `*.bitrix24.*`.
>
> Please note that the following addresses should be allowed as well in order to provide simaltaneous work of such services as telephony, bots, open channels, videos: `*.bitrix.info`, `bitrix*.cdnvideo.ru`, `*.cloudfront.net`

https://helpdesk.bitrix24.com/open/6355275/

Bitrix telephony, bots, open channels and videos work through the cloud server.